# Why is cursor position not always predictable during formatting?

Tags: javascript

When text is formatted by Javascript the final cursor position doesn't seem entirely predictable.

1. Sometimes the cursor is moved to the end of the newly formatted text.
2. Sometimes the cursor stays in the middle of the formatted text like a word processor.

Is there a rule I can follow that will allow me to predict the cursor's final position?

The example below is a simplified phone number formatting script.  `e.target.value` is used to get the value after a `keyup`. The value is then formatted to look like a phone number and pushed back into the document also using `e.target.value`.  Super simple.

```js
'use strict';
 
document.getElementsByClassName('input_style')[0].addEventListener('keyup', releaseKey); 

function releaseKey(e) {
 
  let phoneValue, phoneLength;
  
  phoneValue = e.target.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  phoneLength = phoneValue.length; 
  
  if (phoneLength < 3) {
    e.target.value = phoneValue; 
  } else if (phoneLength < 6 ) {
    e.target.value = '(' +phoneValue.substring(0, 3) +') ' +phoneValue.substring(3);
  } else {
    phoneValue = phoneValue.substring(0, 10);
    e.target.value = '(' +phoneValue.substring(0, 3) +') ' +phoneValue.substring(3, 6) +'-' +phoneValue.substring(6, 10);
  } 

}
```

```css
.input_style {
 flex: 1 0 auto;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<input class="input_style" placeholder="(555) 555-5555">
```

1. If you enter a 10 digit number the cursor moves forward as you type as expected.
2. Editing this 10 digit number also works as expected.  Move the cursor to any position inside the 10 digits and type a new number.  This new number pushes the other numbers forward and the last digit drops off.  After each `keyup` and function iteration the cursor moves to the end of the phone number as expected.
3. However seemingly unpredictable behavior occurs if you edit the phone number BEFORE all 10 digits have been entered.
4. As an example enter 7 digits. Position the cursor before the 7th digit and enter a new number.  The cursor adds the new number at position 7 and pushes the old one up to position 8.  **However the key difference is that the cursor stays in position like a word processor**.  This allows you to type more numbers up to 10.  After the `keyup` and function iteration why didn't the cursor move to the end line as it did before?  It isn't necessarily because you hadn't typed in a full 10 digits because if you try this with 3 digits it sends the cursor to the end as it did before.
5. Long story short `e.target.value` is being read and replaced each function iteration.  Sometimes the cursor moves to the end of the line, sometimes it stays in the middle.  Is there a rule for this behavior? Thanks so much!